# php artisan make:controller PostsController --resource: --resource not generating functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When running
`php artisan make:controller PostsController --resource`,
the `index`, `create`, `show` etc. functions are not generated.
I also tried `-r` but no luck,
are `--resource/-r` depracated?

Is it fine if I'll just manually create it?

Please help

Laravel Version : 8.11.2

Comment: `php artisan make:controller PostsController --resource` it is tested in laravel 8 working fine check with your installation something wrong with it

Comment: Why should such actions be created automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Resource flag is not depreciated. I can use it and both -r and --resource are working fine. Did your laravel installation completed without any errors? and also please specify the exact version of laravel you are using.

**And yes, You can create all the methods manually.** It is completely fine.

Moreover, you can add `help` keyword before any artisan command to see all the available options. For Example: `php artisan help make:controller`

Comment: it did just fine. my version is 8.11.2

Im sorry. Im very new on asking questions on stackoverflow :D 
I have not edted well my question xD

Comment: Use the help keyword and see if --resource option is available which it most probably will. Then run the make controller command with -r again, if it still doesn't create the required methods then there is something wrong with the installation. But if this is the only problem, don't worry about it and make the methods manually.

Answer (score 0):

use "php artisan list". It will provide you list of paramaters.
Also you can create it manually.

Comment: i tried it and it shows commands including Options commands, mine is not showing -r. Isn't it suppose to be there? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This command works fine Tested in "Laravel 7", check your installation and try running

```
php artisan list
```

it will show all the available commands in your Laravel project, and instead of doing

```
php artisan make:controller ControllerName -r
```

try

```
PHP artisan make:model ModelName -mcr
```

it will generate all the Model,Migration and Resource Controller all together

Answer (score 0):

if you already creat postscontroller and controller not provide index, create, edit funtion then delete your postscontroller &  run this command in your terminal in new file you have index, creat etc.  php artisan make:controller PostsController --resource

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).